# Real time update total

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

As you can see in the image, every time I click + or - the total should update.

[Image  1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KROR.png)

[Image total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOlrQ.png)

This is my html code of the box in the image:

```html
<div class="qty mt-5">
    <span class="minus minus-triangolo"></span>
    <input type="text" class="count count-triangolo" name="quantita_cialda_triangolo" value="0" id="quantita_cialda_triangolo" autocomplete="off">
    <span class="plus plus-triangolo"></span>
    <label class="title-piu">Cialda a triangolo<span>“Confezione da 6 pezzi”</span></label>
</div>
```

This is  my jQuery:

```js
function calcPrice() {
    var price = 0;
    var $panna  = $('#panna').is(':checked');
    var $radio1  = $('#radio1').is(':checked');
    var $radio2  = $('#radio2').is(':checked');
    var $radio3  = $('#radio3').is(':checked');
    var $radio4  = $('#radio4').is(':checked'); 
    var $cialda1 = $("input[name=quantita_cialda_triangolo]").val();
    var $valcialda1  = 3;    

    $("input[name=peso][data-price]:checked").each(function(i, el) {
        price += +$(el).data("price");
    });

    if( $panna && $radio1 ){
            price = 3 + price;
    }

    if( $panna && $radio2 ){
            price = 5 + price;
    }

    if( $panna && $radio3 ){
            price = 5 + price;
    }

    if( $panna && $radio4 ){
            price = 5 + price;
    }

    function multiply(a, b) {
        return a * b;
    }

    var $m1 = multiply($cialda1, $valcialda1);
    price = $m1 + price;

    $("#totale").text(price);
}

$("input[type=radio]").on("change", calcPrice);
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", calcPrice);

calcPrice();
```

The code for + / -

```js
$('.count-triangolo').prop('disabled', true);
$(document).on('click','.plus-triangolo',function(){
    $('.count-triangolo').val(parseInt($('.count-triangolo').val()) + 1 );
});

$(document).on('click','.minus-triangolo',function(){
    $('.count-triangolo').val(parseInt($('.count-triangolo').val()) - 1 );
    if ($('.count-triangolo').val() == 0) {
        $('.count-triangolo').val(0);
    }
});
```

The jQuery works perfectly with the other inputs (radio, check), basically whenever something happens, the total is updated, but I can't update it in real time by clicking on the + or -.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add `$('.minus-triangolo, .plus-triangolo').on('click', calcPrice);` ... or if this click event exists, than at the end add `calcPrice()`

Comment: @skobaljic I had already tried that solution.
the counter starts from 0, if I click on + it goes to 1, but the total remains at 0. If I add again the total updates, but incorrectly.

Comment: You haven't posted your plus/minus Javascript events... how do you handle them? In case those buttons are added later, than you can use event delegation as `$('body').on('click', '.minus-triangolo, .plus-triangolo', calcPrice);

Comment: @skobaljic i add it, sorry

Comment: So, inside those 2 events, `$(document).on('click','.plus-triangolo',function(){...});` (and minus), at the end just add `calcPrice();` - also make sure that calcPrice function is in global scope.

Comment: @skobaljic thanks, it works!